# Jquery clone('true') preventing draggable

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to clone an SVG image and then make get the double click event and make it draggable. For some reason (that I hope you can tell me) my code is not working. It is only double clickable or if I remove the 'true' from the clone() method it is only draggable but I cannot make it both. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var c = 0;
    $('svg[id^=draggable_bull_]').draggable({
      start: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).draggable('option','revert',false)     
      }
    });   
    $('svg[id^=draggable_bull_').on('dblclick',function(){
    alert();
    });         
    $("button").on('click',function(){  
    $('#draggable_bull_0').clone(true).attr('id', 'draggable_bull_'+(++c)   ).appendTo("body").draggable();     
     });        
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="click">CLICK TO CLONE</button>      

    <svg
    width="16px"
    height="16px"
    id="draggable_bull_0">
    <defs id="defs2987" />
    <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
    borderopacity="1.0"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pageshadow="2"
    inkscape:zoom="22.197802"
    inkscape:cx="8"
    inkscape:cy="8"
    inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
    showgrid="true"
    inkscape:grid-bbox="true"
    inkscape:document-units="px"
    inkscape:window-width="792"
    inkscape:window-height="691"
    inkscape:window-x="150"
    inkscape:window-y="150"
    inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
    <g
    id="layer1"
    inkscape:label="Layer 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer">
    <path
    sodipodi:type="arc"
    style="fill:#ececec;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-     linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
    id="path2993"
    sodipodi:cx="8.0188122"
    sodipodi:cy="7.891089"
    sodipodi:rx="5.9915843"
    sodipodi:ry="5.7212873"
    d="m 14.010396,7.891089 a 5.9915843,5.7212873 0 1 1 -11.9831681,0 5.9915843,5.7212873 0   1 1 11.9831681,0 z" />
   </g>
    </svg> </body>
       </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.
This is what I did:
I changed this line ( I removed the true from clone() )

```
 $('#draggable_bull_0').clone().attr('id', 'draggable_bull_'+(++c)   ).appendTo("body").draggable();
```

Now the problem I am left with is the double click event is not firing. 
So I did this:

```
$( '#draggable_bull_'+c ).on( "dblclick", function() {
             alert( $(this).attr('id') );
        });
```

It looks like this:

```
$("button").on('click',function(){  
        $('#draggable_bull_0').clone().attr('id', 'draggable_bull_'+(++c)   ).appendTo("body").draggable(); 

        $( '#draggable_bull_'+c ).on( "dblclick", function() {
             alert( $(this).attr('id') );
        }); 
     });
```

I hope this helps someone.